# tkinter ttk Button command problem in combination with self class

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have a problem: when I add a button to my tkinter application, the command attribute doesn't work properly. I tried many things but it didn't work.
can someone help me?

my code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import turtle


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.width = 1910
        self.height = 828
        self.geometry(f"{self.width}x{self.height}+-10+0")

        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        self.text.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, side=tk.LEFT)

        self.run = ttk.Button(self, text="run", command=self.turtle.arc(-90, 90, 100))  # doesn't work
        self.run.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.config()
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(self.canvas)
        self.pen = turtle.RawTurtle(self.screen)

        self.turtle = self.Turtle(self)

    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()

    class Turtle:
        def __init__(self, app):
            self.pen = app.pen

        def arc(self, afrom, ato, r):
            self.pen.seth(afrom)
            self.pen.up()
            self.pen.right(90)
            self.pen.forward(r)
            self.pen.left(90)
            self.pen.down()
            self.pen.circle(ato - afrom, r)
            self.pen.left(90)
            self.pen.forward(r)
            self.pen.left(90)
```

I think the problem is in the following:

```
self.run = ttk.Button(self, text="run", command=self.turtle.arc(-90, 90, 100))  # doesn't work
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: It's `command=`, not `callback=`.  But the value has to be a function (which will be called with no parameters), you're calling the function yourself (which will happen at the time the Button is created).

Comment: you're right... i always forget that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
# use a lambda to call an anonymous function as the 'command'
self.run = ttk.Button(self, text="run", command=lambda: self.turtle.arc(-90, 90, 100))
```

And yes, as has been pointed out, you want to use `command` not `callback`